# python gevent in function that is not patchable

Tags: python, gunicorn, gevent

I'm working in a REST service that is basically an wrapper to a library. I'm using flask and gunicorn. Basically each endpoint in the service maps to a different function in the library.

It happens that some of the calls to the library can take a long time to return, and that is making my service run out of workers once the service starts receiving a few requests. Right now I'm using the default gunicorn workers (sync).

I wanted to use gevent workers in order to be able to receive more requests, because not every endpoint takes that long to execute. However the function in the library does not use any of the patchable gevent functions, meaning that it won't cooperatively schedule to another green thread.

I had this idea of using a pool of threads or processes to handle the calls to the library asynchronously, and then each green thread produced by gunicorn would sleep until the process is not finished. Does this idea make sense at all?

Is it possible to use the multiprocessing.Process with gevent? and then have the join method to give up control to another green thread, and only return when the process is finished?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it makes perfect sense to use (real) threads or processes from within `gevent` for code that needs to be asynchronous but can't be monkeypatched by `gevent`.

Of course it can be tricky to get right—first, because you may have monkeypatched `threading`, and second, because you want your cooperative threads to be able to block on a pool or a pool result without blocking the whole main thread.

But that's exactly what [`gevent.threadpool`](http://www.gevent.org/api/gevent.threadpool.html) is for.

If you would have used `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` in a non-`gevent` app, monkeypatch `threading` and then use `gevent.threadpool.ThreadPoolExecutor`.

If you would have used `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` in a non-`gevent` app, monkeypatch `threading` and then use `gevent.threadpool.ThreadPool`.

Either way, methods like `map`, `submit`, `apply_async`, etc. work pretty much the way you'd expect. The `Future` and `AsyncResult` objects play nice with greenlets; you can `gevent.wait` things, or attach callbacks (which will run as greenlets), etc. Most of the time it just works like magic, and the rest of the time it's not too hard to figure out.

---

Using processes instead of threads is doable, but not as nice. AFAIK, there's no wrappers for anything as complete as `multiprocessing.Process` or `multiprocessing.Pool`, and trying to use the normal `multiprocessing` just hangs. You can manually [`fork`](http://www.gevent.org/api/gevent.html#working-with-muliple-processes) if you're not on Windows, but that's about all that's built in. If you really need multiprocessing, you may need to do some multi-layered thing, where your greenlets don't talk to a process, but instead talk to a thread that creates a pipe, forks, execs, and then proxies between the gevent world and the child process.

If the calls are taking a long time because they're waiting on I/O from a backend service, or waiting on a subprocess, or doing GIL-releasing numpy work, I wouldn't bother trying to do `multiprocessing`. But if they're taking a long time because they're burning CPU… well, then you either need to get multiprocessing working, or go lower-level and just spin off a `subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'workerscript.py'])`.